# iPhone/iPad. How do I launch an app from link in Safari?

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari, ipod-touch

I have an app that I want to be launchable either explicitly when tapped or when a parameterized URL is clicked on on a webpage in Safari running on iPad or iPhone.

Can someone sketch the approach for me and/or point me to the relevant docs? Thanks so much.

Cheers,
Doug

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You basically need to register your own URL scheme in Info.plist, and your app becomes launchable. If you want to fine-tune the app behavior when launching from an URL, you can parse the parameters that are passed to your app as part of the URL, and do whatever you wish based on those.

[Here’s the official Apple guide about the same topic.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1)

Comment: From SO's help center: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I added context and another link.