# Push viewcontroller when OpenURL is called for DeepLinking

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking, openurl

I need to push a viewcontroller when open

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options
```

method is called.

It is working fine when app is in background. But when I have killed the app and the link is clicked, it is not getting pushed. I have a tab bar controller setup in `didFinishLaunch` method. Will didFinish be called after `openURL` ?

Comment: can you explain little bit clear. after killing the app, where you are clicking the link?

Comment: @TysonVignesh - I am clicking the link in my website, which in turn triggers the applink.

Comment: from safari to your app?

Comment: @TysonVignesh - Yes.

Comment: please look at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655366/iphone-ipad-how-do-i-launch-an-app-from-link-in-safari,

Answer (score 0):

If your application is not running, you will be called to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method with a URL [Launch Option Key](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Launch_Options_Keys).

To handle it, check for `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` key in the launch options and extract the URL:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] != nil) {
        // Opened from an URL
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It was because, appdelegate `didFinishLaunch`method is called when app is launched by applink. I am using FBSDK and returning

`return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];`

This will return false in case of my custom scheme. So I explicitly calls this, by checking my URL scheme.

`if ([launchURL.scheme isEqualToString:@"urlScheme"]) {

        [self application:application
                  openURL:launchURL
        sourceApplication:sourceApplication
               annotation:@""];
    }`

Putting the above code before returning didFinishLaunch solved my issue.