# Methods not called after openURL function ONLY if app is not active

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, deep-linking, openurl

After visiting a share url on a website, viewers are prompted to open the link in my application. If the application is running, it works perfectly.

However, if the application is closed, the `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` methods are not called on my ViewController, so I am not able to open the desired ViewController.

Does anyone know how to allow to get the `viewDidLoad` function to run if the app is launched from the `openURL` function?

I currently have:

**AppDelegate:**

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    if (!url) { return NO; }

    NSString *party_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/", PARTYURL, url.lastPathComponent];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:@"WebViewNotification" object:party_url]];
    return YES;
}
```

**ViewController:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appDelegate = [AppDelegate getDelegate];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(webViewNotification:) name:@"WebViewNotification" object:nil];
}

- (void)webViewNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSString *url = [notification object];
    PartyViewController *partyViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PartyViewController"];
    partyViewController.partyUrl = url;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:partyViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Again, this works fine if the app was previously opened. However, if it is closed, this does not work. Thank you!

Comment: Just a guess: I think you need to instantiate and push your partyViewController directly in `openURL:`, instead of sending the notification. Did you set a breakpoint in `openURL:`, does that get called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone/iPad. How do I launch an app from link in Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655366/iphone-ipad-how-do-i-launch-an-app-from-link-in-safari)

Comment: @Koen I tried pushing it directly there, but it didn't work for me based on how my navigation controllers are setup. The `openURL:` method gets called successfully in both scenarios.

Comment: So in which ViewController is the code above located?

Comment: @Koen I have a CustomTabBarController underneath a presented ViewController. The presented ViewController contains the code shown above.

Comment: BTW, the `openURL:` method above has been deprecated, you should consider using https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application?language=objc

Answer (score 1):

When your app launched from a link without any other operation you don't have a presented ViewController contains this code in your views stacks. so this code will never been executed. consider directly present partyViewController in your CustomTabBarController.